# ms access group by gives strange characters

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access 2013 database and seeing a strange result when bringing in a long text value from one table.

Instead of the field data, my query returns foreign characters like:
 儥d ᐫd 봚c 瀎d 젓d ഡe തe ഥe ഩe ധe ㈚f 爡f 頀f 頂f ㈥g ㈱g ਆh 㬛h 퀗k
and many others instead of the data contained in the field

I have already worked around the issue by removing the GROUP BY.  I was also able to make the field data appear correctly if decreased the query from returning 8 fields to 4 fields, I  but would like to know if anyone knows why this is happening.

Thankyouverymuch!

Comment: i've had these happen to me too, i think it's because data type is not recognizable by access. I usually do cstr(columnname) on those to convert to string.

Comment: It's not the data type, it's just a weird bug. Probably some Unicode handling that goes South.